# i want to use same cache using ehcache for all requests of different clients

Tags: web-services, jakarta-ee, caching, ehcache

eh-cache uses different different cache for each client who is accessing the web service.I am using it. I want to use same cache for all clients. what i need to configure so that it will use same cache instead creating new cache for each client. Now it is creating new cache for each client.

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17652178/does-ehcache-uses-same-cache-for-all-clients/17660140. answer is there...

Answer (score 0):

You should use distributed eh-cache that shares common cache among eh-cache client instances. For this you need to update your eh-cache jar files with Terracotta implementation of eh-cache. Also your ehcache.xml configuration has to be updated to enable terracotta.
See it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14504507/ehcache-hibernate-terracotta-versions/15703973#15703973)